# Detach and move element after completing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, css-animations

I have a list of items with a close button associated with each item. When clicked, animation plays, list slides up and the item is removed successfully .

```
$(document).on("click", ".close-button", function(e) { //removes with animation
    $(this).parent().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 250, function() {
        $(this).animate({
                marginBottom: 0
            }, 250)
            .children()
            .animate({
                padding: 0
            }, 250)
            .wrapInner("<div />")
            .children()
            .slideUp(250, function() {
                $(this).closest(".element").remove();
            });
    });
});
```

I attempted to modify the above piece of code so that instead of removing the item, I detach the item and move it to another view. I attempted this  using the below code, to no avail.
`$(this).closest('.element').detach().prependTo('#diff-view').hide().slideDown(250)`

Getting rid of the animations moves the element to a different view successfully.

```
$(document).on("click", ".close-button" ,function(e) { //detaches w/o animation
  $(this).closest('.element').detach().prependTo('#diff-view').hide().slideDown(250)
});
```

I want to keep the animations of course, but I just can't figure out how to detach instead of remove while keeping them in place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is remove working?

Comment: @Satpal Just commented it out to check. There's no visual difference, but I checked the document, and apparently it is not working... The html is still there, just hidden. I was not aware

Answer (score 1):

As you are animating parent `this` refers to the animated element. As result reference to close button is lost.

Store the reference of element of current element and the use later to target.

```
$(document).on("click", ".close-button", function (e) { 
    //Store the reference
    var $this= $(this);
    $(this).parent().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 250, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            marginBottom: 0
        }, 250)
        .children()
        .animate({
            padding: 0
        }, 250)
        .wrapInner("<div />")
        .children()
        .slideUp(250, function () {
            $this.closest('.element').prependTo('#diff-view').hide().slideDown(250)
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand having to store the reference now, but it is still not moving the element to the other view. It removes using `.remove()`, which is great. I can't understand how prepending works without all the anims but it doesn't here...

Comment: I used `.clone()` in front of `.prependTo()` and it works. I'm losing references by using `clone()` instead of `.detach()` but we'll see if this has any impact later on.